# How to use GZip when saving datatable to Azure blob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have written a C# application to archive data from a SQL Server table into an Azure blob. The archiving is configured by a JSON file and the values retrieved from the JSON file dictate what data to retrieve and archive.

The data needs to be stored in a blob name in this format

```
year/month/day/hour/older-than-[query-date]
```

Where query-date is the current date minus a number of days specified in the JSON file.

The issue I am having is how to incorporate compression to the process.

We would like to compress the data being archived to save space.

Currently the JSON settings mean that any data only than 30 days should be archived, but this results in about 3.7 million rows of data, so sometimes I get out of memory exceptions.

Regardless, how can I compress using GZip each row of data to the Azure blob? Here is existing code.

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adr = new SqlDataAdapter(comm))
{
    adr.Fill(data);
    data.TableName = config.TargetTableName;
}

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("blank");
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
blobClient.DefaultRequestOptions.ParallelOperationThreadCount = 20;
blobClient.DefaultRequestOptions.MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
blobClient.DefaultRequestOptions.ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(config.AzureContainerName);

StringBuilder jsonData = new StringBuilder();
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"{config.TargetTableName}/{DateTime.Now.Year}/{DateTime.Now.Month}/{DateTime.Now.Day}/{DateTime.Now.Hour}/Older-Than-{queryParameter.Value}.log");
using (var writeStream = blob.OpenWrite())
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
    {
        data.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you write your data to a MemoryStream. Then we can compress the memory stream and write it to Azure Blob Service. Code below is for your reference.

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"{config.TargetTableName}/{DateTime.Now.Year}/{DateTime.Now.Month}/{DateTime.Now.Day}/{DateTime.Now.Hour}/Older-Than-{queryParameter.Value}.log");

using (var writeStream = blob.OpenWrite())
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
    {
        data.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
    }

    using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(writeStream,
                  CompressionMode.Compress))
    {
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        memoryStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would I specify the filename for the file in the storage?

Comment: You could specify the filename in container.GetBlockBlobReference method. I added a line of code to my sample code.